# params is not being set in rails object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my params i have value batch_params[:end_date]
If i try `Batch.new(end_date: "12/12/12")` **then it works just fine.**
But if i write it like `Batch.new(end_date: batch_params[:end_date])` **it sets batch end date to nil**. I have checked batch_params[:end_date] it contains "12/12/12". Don't know what exactly is going on.

Here is my batch_params function

```
def batch_params
  params.require(:batch).permit( :name, :start_date, :students, :end_date, :course_ids, :batch_id)
end
```

Any help would be appriciated

Here is what i am doing[image]

Comment: Nah, this can't be.

Comment: btw, the whole reason why you have `batch_params` is so that you can do `Batch.new(batch_params)`

Comment: It looks like Rails is expecting the date to be in `yyyy/mm/dd` or `yyyy-mm-dd` format. `12/12/12` was interpreted as `0012-12-12` and `04/29/2017` might be getting interpreted as nil for some reason. Get the formats right and see what happens then. Or you can just make sure batch_params[:end_date] is the *exactly 12/12/12* to test my hypothesis.

Comment: Show your model. I smell some pre-processing.

Comment: yes @whattsIn you are right, date format is wrong, as i have declared end_date as date. An d i am using date-picker jquery. That is setting "dd/mm/yyyy" but rails is accepting "mm/dd/yyyy". Thanks :)

Comment: If you use Batch.new, then your data won't persist when your debugger goes past line 31. How come you don't use Batch.create instead of .new?